# Correct way to get usb devices and its filesystem in C

Tags: c, linux

what would be the proper way to programatically find usb devices and its filesystem.

I am trying to make a small c utility that mounts usbs, what i don't understand is how do i specifically find devices that are usb and how do you go about interacting with the drive to get information such as what filesystem it has. (I hope this makes it easier to understand)

Comment: Can you do this with standard command line tools?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sorry, i'm still unsure as how to properly ask a programming question.

Comment: For starters you need to include code.

Comment: Start by tagging the question with usb. C and Linux don't capture what you're asking. Then explain what you've done to study the Linux documents and look for examples. Then show the code you've written that isn't working as intended. Explain where it's breaking. In this manner you'll probably get the help you want. Thanks.